# Error al cargar un archivo Java

Tags: java

en resúmen estoy tratando de cargar dos archivos de texto con un método load en la clase Cliente que ahora mostraré a continuación, al parecer, uno de ellos se carga sin problema, tengo fallos con el segundo y no sé por qué podría ser.

Voy a explicar cada una de las clases con las que estoy trabajando, primero tenemos la clase Cita, cada cita estará asociada a una citaId de valor numérico (la primera cita es citaId=1, la segunda citaId=2, y así sucesivamente), numCitas es el contador de las citas y por último tenemos un array de string en la que se le añade un texto sobre la valoración de cada cita (a esto no le vamos a hacer caso ahora)

```html
import auxiliar.Format;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Cita {
    private static int numCitas = 0; 
    private final int citaId; 
    private final ArrayList<String> valoraciones; 

    public static void inicializaNumCitas() {
        numCitas = 0; 
    }

    public Cita() {
        this.citaId = ++numCitas;
        this.valoraciones = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public Cita(int citaId) {
        this.citaId = citaId;
        this.valoraciones = null;
    }   

    public int getCitaId() {
        return this.citaId;
        
    }

    //poner antes trim que toLowerCase para ahorrar poner en minuscula los espacios.
    public boolean addValoracion(String valoracion) {
        if (valoracion == null || valoracion.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
        this.valoraciones.add(valoracion.trim().toLowerCase());
        return true;
    }

    public boolean contienePalabra(String palabra){
        //en la comprobación no hace falta hacer un trim()
        if (palabra == null || palabra.isEmpty()) return false;
        for(String s : this.valoraciones) {
            if(s.contains(palabra.trim().toLowerCase())) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.valoraciones.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //hacemos dos comprobaciones, primero si esta vacio y segundo si es nulo.
        return "Cita #" + Format.formatInt(citaId, 4) + " -> " + (this.valoraciones.isEmpty() || this.valoraciones == null ? "<sin texto>" : this.valoraciones.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true; //si this y o son sinónimos (apuntan al mismo objeto), está claro que son iguales
        if (!(o instanceof  Cita)) return false; //si el parámetro no es de tipo Cita, devuelve false
        Cita otraCita = (Cita) o; // Realizamos un casting de Object a Cita
        return citaId == otraCita.citaId; // Comparamos los identificadores de cita
    }

}
```

La siguiente clase es la de Mascota, cada mascota estará identificada por dos claves, el nombre y la especie, además cada mascota tendrá un registro de citas mediante una LinkedList, otro aspecto a destacar de la clase es que usa las interfaces Comparable e Iterable

```html
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;



public class Mascota implements Comparable<Mascota>, Iterable<Cita> {
    private final String nombre;
    private final String especie;
    private final LinkedList<Cita> historial;

    public Mascota(String nombre, String especie) {
        this.nombre = nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty() ? "sinNombre" : nombre.trim().toLowerCase();
        this.especie = especie == null || especie.isEmpty() ? "sinEspecie" : especie.trim().toLowerCase();
        this.historial = new LinkedList<>(); //es igual que poner new LinkedList<Cita>();
    }   

    public Cita addCita() {
        Cita cita = new Cita();
        this.historial.add(cita);
        return cita;
    }

    //index of devuelve un valor numerico dependiendo de si esta o no en la linked list
    public Cita getCita(int citaId) {
        if(citaId < 0) return null;
        int index = this.historial.indexOf(new Cita(citaId));
        return (index >= 0) ? historial.get(index) : null;
    }

    //primero borramos el contenido de historial y luego eliminamos historial en sí (para que el contenido no se quede en el aire)
    public void clear() {
        for(Cita c : historial) {
            c.clear();
        }
        this.historial.clear();
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.historial.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //como tenemos el metodo size() no es necesario poner this.historial.size()
        return this.nombre + " <" + this.especie + "> [" + size() + " cita" + (size() == 1 ?  "" : "s") + "]";
    }

    public String toStringExtended() {
        return this.toString() + ": " + this.historial.toString();
    }

    //Nota: para comparar de forma descendente se pone primero other y luego this
    //El orden natural considera que a es menor (A > Z) tabla ascii
    //No hace falta poner trim y toLowerCase porque al declararlo ya lo hemos puesto.
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Mascota other) {
        int cmp = this.nombre.compareTo(other.nombre);
        return cmp != 0 ? cmp : this.especie.compareTo(other.especie);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Mascota)) return false;
        return this.compareTo((Mascota)other) == 0; 
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Cita> iterator() {
        return this.historial.iterator();
    }
}
```

```
Por último tenemos la clase Cliente, esta clse tendrá un contador numClientes, una clave nombre que identifica a cada cliente y un arrayList de mascotas, en la que se almacena cada mascota de cada cliente, voy a poner la clase entera en la que habrá muchos métodos pero me quiero centrar en el último, el método load, que está al final.
```

```html
import auxiliar.Format;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cliente implements Iterable<Mascota>, Comparable<Cliente>{
    private static int numClientes = 0;
    private final String nombre;
    private final ArrayList<Mascota> mascotas;

    public static void inicializaNumClientes() {
        numClientes = 0;
    }

    
    public Cliente(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = Format.formatInt(++numClientes, 5) + ".- " + (nombre == null || nombre.isEmpty() ? " sinNombre" : nombre.toLowerCase());
        this.mascotas = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addMascota(String nombre, String especie) {
        Mascota m = new Mascota(nombre, especie);
        int index = this.mascotas.indexOf(m);
        if (index >= 0) return false; 
        return this.mascotas.add(m); //por defecto devuelve true
    }

    public Cita addCita(String nombre, String especie) {
        int index = this.mascotas.indexOf(new Mascota(nombre, especie));
        return index != -1 ? this.mascotas.get(index).addCita() : null; //usamos el metodo addcita de Mascota

    }

    public void clear() {
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            m.clear();
        }
        this.mascotas.clear();
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.mascotas.size();
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getCitasId(){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> aux;
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            aux = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Cita c : m) {
                aux.add(c.getCitaId());
            }
            result.add(aux); 
        }
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getCitasId(String palabra) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> aux;
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            aux = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Cita c : m) {
                if(c.contienePalabra(palabra)) aux.add(c.getCitaId());
            }
            result.add(aux);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getCitasId(String nombre, String especie){
        int index = this.mascotas.indexOf(new Mascota(nombre, especie));
        if(index == -1) return null; 
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Cita c : this.mascotas.get(index)) {
            result.add(c.getCitaId());
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Cita getCita(int citaId){
        Cita result = null;
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            result = m.getCita(citaId);
            if(result != null) break;
            }
        return result;
    }

    public Mascota getMascota(int citaId){
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            if(m.getCita(citaId) != null) return m; //si existe la cita devolvemos la mascota
        }
        return null; //sino existe la cita devolvemos nulo.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombre + " -> " + this.mascotas.toString();
    }

    public String toStringExtended() {
        String result = this.nombre + " -> {";
        int cont = 0;
        for(Mascota m : this.mascotas) {
            result += (cont++ != 0 ? ", " : "") + m.toStringExtended();
        }
        return result + "}";
    }

    public boolean load(String nombreArchivo) {
        Scanner scan;
        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new File(nombreArchivo));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String linea = scan.nextLine(); 
            if (linea.isEmpty()) continue;
            if (linea.startsWith("%")) continue;
            String[] items = linea.split("[ ]+");
            int posInicial = items[0].isEmpty() ? 1 : 0;
            Mascota mascota = new Mascota(items[posInicial], items[posInicial+1]);
            
            if(this.mascotas.contains(mascota)) continue;
            this.mascotas.add(mascota);
            int nCitas = Integer.parseInt(items[posInicial + 2]); 
            for (int i = 0; i < nCitas; i++) { //Usamos el for para contar y guardar el nuemro de citas de cada mascota, se recorre tantas veces como numero de citas haya
                mascota.addCita();
            }
        }
        scan.close();
        return true;
    }
    
    //Parte extra
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (this == other) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Cliente)) return false; //instanceof compara que los dos objetos que estes comparando sean de la misma clase
        return this.compareTo((Cliente)other) == 0; 
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cliente otro) {
        return this.nombre.substring(8).compareTo(otro.nombre.substring(8));
    }
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<Mascota> iterator() {
        return this.mascotas.iterator();
    }
}
```

Lo que hace el método load básicamente es que:

- Mientras está leyendo el archivo de texto y siguen habiendo líneas por leer continua
- Si la línea está vacía o comienza con %, continúa con la siguiente linea
- Tenemos un array items que divide la cadena de texto cuando haya uno o varios espacios en blanco (ahora veremos concretamente los archivos de texto)
- Si la linea comienza con un espacio en blanco, la posición inicial será 1, en caso contrario será 0 (habrá alguna línea que comience con varios espacios).
- Creamos un objeto Mascota con el nombre y especie.